# Addition of profile tags for professionals

Tags: feature-request

Wouldn't it be great if Stack Overflow would add personal profile tags which signify that a person is an advanced programmer or a consistent Stack Overflow user. These people would be the highest ranked people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You mean the [fanatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic) badge and [gold tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)?

Comment: You too can get the fanatic badge! Just log in 100 days in a row :)

Comment: Reputation is already a rank, and Joundill already mentioned badges. Additionally, beside reputation, how in the world could you possible "rate" users like that? Plus, at least for SO, someone who is a master a C might, for whatever reason, not know anything about Python or JS.

Comment: This is literally how reputation and badges work right now and have since the site's launch.

Answer (score 2):

> Wouldn't it be great if Stack Overflow would add personal profile tags which signify that a person is an advanced programmer

Yes, it would be great and it already exists!

[image: top tags of a user on Stack Overflow]

The above means the user most likely knows their way in C#, Java, and the rest of those golden tags. Leaving it as bonus quiz to find which user I used as example. :)

Comment: Jon is truly the world's foremost expert in strings.

Comment: @CodyGray no doubt, he can start a fashion company and make millions. :D

Comment: Ooops, you Googled "C string", didn't you?

Comment: @CodyGray of course, nice results there.